# display filename upload using javascript

Tags: javascript, upload, filenames

I want to show the file name while uploading the file.Filename should display in span id="filename"

```
<p>
    <label style="width: 30%">Image</label>
    <label class="custom-file-upload" style="width: 23%"> 
        <input type="file" name="img_1" id="img_1"/> <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Image 1
    </label>
    <span id="filename">none selected...</span> 
</p>
```

if I use this js code ,the file name will display in the label

```
$("input[id='img_1']").change(function (e) {
var $this = $(this);
$this.next().html($this.val().split('\\').pop());});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Can't you use the following in your change method? $("#filename").html($this.val().split('\\').pop()); . Should the file name show up only when upload button is clicked?

Comment: thank you so much.It's done

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$("#filename").html($this.val().split('\\').pop());
```